# printing statement with operator ? : causes unexpected output

Tags: java, operators

I had to create an output depending on an boolean state like

```
  String smily = null;
  StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
  buff.append(", " + smily == null ? ":)" : ":("); //$NON-NLS-1$

  System.out.println(buff.toString());
```

The problem is the String creation statement

```
  ", " + smily == null ? ":)" : ":("
```

I tested it in 2 different eclipse environments (and may be also 2 diofferent java version, this i did not checked) and the result was different.

**Result 1:**

> :(

**Result 2:**

> false:(

Of course, if i added brackets it is working

```
 buff.append(", " + (smily == null ? ":)" : ":(")); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

**Expected Result:**

> , :)

**Can please somebody explain to me, why java interprets the statement that way?**

Thanks

Comment: mention your eclipse jdk version

Comment: Oh and almost forgot, StringBuffer is a NO NO unless you got very strong reasons for it, StringBuilder on the other hand is a YES YES...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the operator precedence (see [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)), then you will notice that addition (`+`) comes before equality (`==`). In other words, Java will first evaluate `", " + smily` => `", null"` before evaluating equality, therefor `", " + smily == null` evaluates to false, and so the ternary operator evaluates to `":("`.

BTW: You could have avoided this by not concatenating strings before adding them to the `StringBuffer` (the whole point of a StringBuffer is to make concatenation cheaper):

```
String smily = null;
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
buff.append(", ");
buff.append(smily == null ? ":)" : ":(");
```

Answer (score 3):

the expression `", " + smily == null ? ":)" : ":("` is evaluated as `(", " + smily) == null ? ":)" : ":("`

This explains your result 1. To be honest, I don't know why result 2 was possible.

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuffer.append()` takes a `String` parameter. So when you put this without brackets

```
buff.append(", " + smily == null ? ":)" : ":(")
```

at the time of evaluation  will be `", " + null`. So when the evaluation happens it is always false.

As for why the same code returned two results I can only assume that two different Java versions were used and they handled this situation differently.

Comment: Smily will still be null, but the actual comparison will be `(", " + smily) == null` or `", null" == null`

Comment: Ah bad phrasing of what I meant to say... Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
String smily = null;
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

  if(smily == null){
    buff.append(", " +  ":)") ; //$NON-NLS-1$
     }else{
        buff.append(", " +   ":(") ; //$NON-NLS-1$

}
```

Comment: He is not looking for a work around, but an explanation `Can please somebody explain this to me.`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.....................**

`buff.append(", " + smily == null ? ":)" : ":(");`

**-** In the above statement you are **Not mentioning** the `smily == null ? ":)" : ":("` to be evaluated in the proper way it has to be.

**-** To solve this you have to use **BODMAS** rule, the below are **always evaluated in the way it has been listed from Left to Right.**

`Bracket`

`Power`

`Division and Multiplication`

`Addition and Substraction`

**-** Use Bracket to enclose the `smily == null ? ":)" : ":("`

**Eg:**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String smily = null;
          StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
          buff.append(", " + (smily == null ? ":)" : ":(")); //$NON-NLS-1$

          System.out.println(buff.toString());
    }

}
```

**Output:**   `, :)`